# accessibilityIdentifier gets lost on real iOS device

Tags: ios, instruments, ios-ui-automation, xcode-instruments

I've run into a weird issue with instruments and automated testing through UIAutomation. For some reason it seems like the accessibilityIdentifier for some buttons are lost when running on a real iOS device, but not in the simulator.

Running the following through instruments yields different results on Simulator vs device:

```
var message = target.frontMostApp().navigationBar().buttons()[3].name();
UIALogger.logDebug("msg: " + message);
```

I get "msg: null" on device vs "msg: nav arrow right" on Simulator.

Could the compiler perhaps be optimizing away the accessibilityIdentifier when building for a real device, since it isn't directly used for anything other than UIAutomation? Any hints are welcome.

Comment: Just to double check, could you add a delay before printing out the log message. I've found that sometimes on device, it takes an extra moment for the UI to be ready. 

A simple message like this should do
    
    UIATarget.delay(1);